# How do I get a value of a class in a JSP using JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Hopefully that title made sense. I'm trying to get the value of the integer age (which is private and has getters and setters) in the class People. ${People.age} isn't bringing anything back. Is there something i'm missing out on? Thank you.

JSP with JSTL:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>  
    <c:set var="ages" value="${People.age}"/>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>
<p style="color:black;font-size:100px">this persin is ${findThatGuy.People.age}</p>
<c:out value="${findThatGuy.People.age}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have getter setter for People class in findThatGuy bean Class. Also make sure you set this in request attribute as setAttribute.

```
public Class findThatGuy{

    private People people;

    public People getPeople(){

        return people;
    }

    public void setPeople(People people){

        this.people = people;
    }
}

httpRequest.setAttribute("findThatGuy", findThatGuy);

In Jsp use
<c:out value="${findThatGuy.people.age}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Where does httpRequest.setAttribute("findThatGuy", findThatGuy); go? Is it under the class, in a servlet?

Comment: Yes you need populate your bean in servlet class or controller if your using spring framework. Recommend way is to use spring mvc framework for web development.

Answer (score 0):

You have a POJO class named `People`, So you can make use of `<jsp:useBean>` to set the value of bean object `people`.

Here, is a [tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-setProperty-and-jsp-getProperty-action-tag) to set property of a bean object.